# Psexec doesnt give me the full results

Tags: powershell, system-administration, psexec

Ive been trying this script using psexec to get processes of a range of pcs, i make it work but i dont get the results on the table that it should appear, ive been searching on psexec posts but i dont know why it gets me the results in half, i cant use Invoke-command or Get-Pssession because firewall/antivirus and GPOS of my org i can make individual exceptions but they get reset everytime the pcs get an update.

[image: The result of the script is this]

[image: How it should appear]

`````
$pathscript = "D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV"
$fpassword = "D:\SCRIPTSM\pswd.json"
$rutaLog = "D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\fallos.log"
$fecha = Date

Set-Location -Path $pathscript

$JsonObject = Get-Content $fpassword | ConvertFrom-Json

$usuario = 'Administrador'
$password = $JsonObject.password


$equipos = "D:\SCRIPTSM\despFi\equinom.txt"
$listaEquipos = Get-Content $equipos

 foreach ($equipo in $listaEquipos){

    if (test-connection -ComputerName $equipo -Count 1 -Quiet){
        
        Set-Location -Path "D:\SCRIPTSM\PSTools"
        .\psexec.exe \\$equipo -u $usuario -p $password -h powershell.exe Get-Process | Select -First 15 Name,ID,VM,PM >> 'D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\PRUEBNOMB.txt'
        Set-Location -Path $pathscript

    }else{

        Write-Output "No se puede conectar al equipo --> $equipo" >> $rutaLog

    }
} ````
`````

Comment: Can u explain a little more is it trying to make 'D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\PRUEBNOMB.txt' on the remote computer?

Comment: You're trying to export objects as if they were just plain text. `>> 'D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\PRUEBNOMB.txt'` should be changed to `| Export-Csv 'D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\PRUEBNOMB.csv'`

Comment: @vonPryz, given that `>>` isn't quoted (and is part of a separate pipeline segment), I expect it to be interpreted by PowerShell up front, i.e. targets the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `Select` ([`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)) call part of the remotely executing PowerShell command, which requires *quoting* the remotely executing command:

```bash
# Note the '...' around the `Get-Process | Select-Object ...` pipeline
.\psexec.exe \\$equipo -u $usuario -p $password -h powershell.exe 'Get-Process | Select -First 15 Name,ID,VM,PM' >> 'D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\PRUEBNOMB.txt'
```

Note:

- You'll capture the *for-display* representation of the processes, as you would see in the console - see alternative below.
- The output is appended to a (caller-)*local* file; if instead you want to save to a file on the *remote* machine, also move the `>>` redirection inside `'...'` (you don't need the `'` around the target file path - just omit them).
- The `'...'` argument containing the command to execute remotely *in full* is implicitly passed to the `-Command` (`c`) parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI.

  - As an aside: With [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, `-Command` (`-c`) *must be specified* when passing commands, because the `-File` parameter for executing *script files* is the default there.

---

If you want to capture *structured data* instead, e.g. CSV, use the following, via [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv):

```bash
.\psexec.exe \\$equipo -u $usuario -p $password -h powershell.exe 'Get-Process | Select -First 15 Name,ID,VM,PM | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation' >> 'D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\PRUEBNOMB.csv'
```

Note:

- Again, if you want to save the output file *remotely*, omit the `>>` redirection altogether and replace `ConvertTo-Csv` with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) and the target file path:
  `... | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\PRUEBNOMB.csv`

---

As for **what you tried**:

- In your attempt, `Select -First 15 Name,ID,VM,PM` runs *locally*, on the *string output* from the remotely executed `Get-Process`.
- Since `[string]` instances have no properties such as `Name`, `ID`, ..., `Select-Object creates custom objects with such properties whose value is` $null`, resulting in the empty output lines you saw.